# Python rpg boss infinite attacking loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a programming beginner making a text-based rpg in python. I have a boss battle set up here to get started. I have created functions for the boss to attack, as well as all of the players. The problem I am having with this code is that I have created a boolean value for if the boss has already attacked once in a turn. This value starts out true, then changes to false at the end of the bosses attacking function. I have set up code where players attack in order of their speed. The boss is first. The conditions for the battle to continue right now are that the boss's health is above 0. For some reason the boss keeps attacking when I first start the battle, even though the value for if she can attack should have been changed to false at the end of her attack function. If she can't attack, the code should move on to the player's attack functions. Here is the code for the battle, the boss's and player's attack functions, and the attempted changing of the boolean value at the bottom.

```
def AriaMove():
   target = Player.NocturneEnemy
   if Player.Aria.hp > 0:
       print("What will Aria do?")
   choice = input()
   if choice == "attack":
       Player.Aria.NormalAttack
   if Player.Aria.attack <= target.defense:
       damage = 0
       target.hp = target.hp - damage
       print("Nocturne's health is:")
       print(target.hp)
   if choice == "healing song: Sereana":
       Player.Sereana.hp + 100
       print("Sereana's health is:")
       print(Player.Sereana.hp)
   if choice == "healing song: Lupin":
       Player.Lupin.hp + 100
       print("Lupin's health is:")
       print(Player.Lupin.hp)
   if choice == "healing song: Aria":
       Player.Aria.hp + 100
       print("Aria's health is:")
       print(Player.Aria.hp)
   if choice == "healing song: Anges":
       Player.Anges.hp + 100
       print("Anges's health is:")
       print(Player.Anges.hp)
   if choice == "healing song: Sylph":
       Player.Sylph.hp + 100
       print("Sylph's health is:")
       print(Player.Sylph.hp)

def AngesMove():
   target = Player.NocturneEnemy
   if Player.Anges.hp > 0:
       print("What will Anges do?")
   choice = input()
   if choice == "attack":
       damage = Player.Anges.attack - target.defense
       target.hp = target.hp - damage
       print("Nocturne's health is:")
       print(target.hp)
   if choice == "pirouette":
       damage = Player.Anges.Pirouette - target.defense
       target.hp = target.hp - damage
       print("Nocturne's health is:")
       print(target.hp)

def SylphMove():
   target = Player.NocturneEnemy
   if Player.Sylph.hp > 0:
       print("What will Sylph do?")
   choice = input()
   if choice == "attack":
       damage = Player.Sylph.attack - target.defense
       if Player.Sylph.attack <= target.defense:
           damage = 0
       target.hp = target.hp - damage
       print("Nocturne's health is:")
       print(target.hp)
   if choice == "health drain":
       damage = (Player.Sylph.attack + 20) - target.defense
       target.hp = target.hp - damage
       Player.Sylph.hp = Player.Sylph.hp + 40
       print("Sylph's health is:")
       print(Player.Sylph.hp)
       print("Nocturne's health is:")
       print(target.hp)

def SereanaMove():
   target = Player.NocturneEnemy
   if Player.Sereana.hp > 0:
       print("What will Sereana do?")
   choice = input()
   if choice == "attack":
       damage = Player.Sereana.attack - target.defense
       target.hp = target.hp - damage
       print(target.hp)
   if choice == "paintbrush spear":
       damage = (Player.Sereana.attack + 30) - target.defense
       target.hp = target.hp - damage
       print("Nocturne's health is:")
       print(target.hp)

def LupinMove():
   target = Player.NocturneEnemy
   if Player.Lupin.hp > 0:
       print("What will Lupin do?")
       choice = input()
   if choice == "attack":
       damage = Player.Lupin.attack - target.defense
       target.hp = target.hp - damage
       print("nocturne's health is:")
       print(target.hp)

def NocturneAttack():
   attackID = random.randint(1, 2)
   targetID = random.randint(1, 5)
   if attackID == 1:
       if targetID == 1 and Player.Sereana.hp > 0:
           target = Player.Sereana
           Nocturnedamage = Player.NocturneEnemy.attack - target.defense
           Player.Sereana.hp = Player.Sereana.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Sereana's health is:")
           print(Player.Sereana.hp)
       elif Player.Sereana.hp < 0:
           targetID = random.randint(2, 5)

       if targetID == 2 and Player.Lupin.hp > 0:
           target = Player.Lupin
           Nocturnedamage = Player.NocturneEnemy.attack - target.defense
           Player.Lupin.hp = Player.Lupin.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Lupin's health is:")
           print(Player.Lupin.hp)
       elif Player.Lupin.hp < 0:
           targetID = random.randint(1, 5)

       if targetID == 3 and Player.Aria.hp > 0:
           target = Player.Aria
           Nocturnedamage = Player.NocturneEnemy.attack - target.defense
           Player.Aria.hp = Player.Aria.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Aria's health is:")
           print(Player.Aria.hp)
       elif Player.Aria.hp < 0:
           targetID = random.randint(1, 5)

       if targetID == 4 and Player.Anges.hp > 0:
           target = Player.Anges
           Nocturnedamage = Player.NocturneEnemy.attack - target.defense
           Player.Anges.hp = Player.Anges.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Anges's health is:")
           print(Player.Anges.hp)
       elif Player.Anges.hp < 0:
           targetID = random.randint(1, 5)

       if targetID == 5 and Player.Sylph.hp > 0:
           target = Player.Sylph
           Nocturnedamage = Player.NocturneEnemy.attack - target.defense
           Player.Sylph.hp = Player.Sylph.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Sylph's health is:")
           print(Player.Sylph.hp)
       elif Player.Sylph.hp < 0:
           targetID = random.randint(1, 4)
           Nocturnedamage = Player.NocturneEnemy.attack - target.defense

   if attackID == 2:
       if targetID == 1 and Player.Sereana.hp > 0:
           target = Player.Sereana
           Nocturnedamage = (Player.NocturneEnemy.attack + 30) - target.defense
           Player.Sereana.hp = Player.Sereana.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Sereana's health is:")
           print(Player.Sereana.hp)
       elif Player.Sereana.hp < 0:
           targetID = random.randint(2, 5)

       if targetID == 2 and Player.Lupin.hp > 0:
           target = Player.Lupin
           Nocturnedamage = (Player.NocturneEnemy.attack + 30) - target.defense
           Player.Lupin.hp = Player.Lupin.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Lupin's health is:")
           print(Player.Lupin.hp)
       elif Player.Lupin.hp < 0:
           targetID = random.randint(1, 5)

       if targetID == 3 and Player.Aria.hp > 0:
           target = Player.Aria
           Nocturnedamage = (Player.NocturneEnemy.attack + 30) - target.defense
           Player.Aria.hp = Player.Aria.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Aria's health is:")
           print(Player.Aria.hp)
       elif Player.Aria.hp < 0:
           targetID = random.randint(1, 5)

       if targetID == 4 and Player.Anges.hp > 0:
           target = Player.Anges
           Nocturnedamage = (Player.NocturneEnemy.attack + 30) - target.defense
           Player.Anges.hp = Player.Anges.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Anges's health is:")
           print(Player.Anges.hp)
       elif Player.Anges.hp < 0:
           targetID = random.randint(1, 5)

       if targetID == 5 and Player.Sylph.hp > 0:
           target = Player.Sylph
           Nocturnedamage = (Player.NocturneEnemy.attack + 30) - target.defense
           Player.Sylph.hp = Player.Sylph.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Sylph's health is:")
           print(Player.Sylph.hp)
       elif Player.Sylph.hp < 0:
           targetID = random.randint(1, 4)
           Nocturnedamage = (Player.NocturneEnemy.attack + 30) - target.defense

       if targetID == 1:
           Player.Sereana.hp = Player.Sereana.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Sereana's health is:")
           print(Player.Sereana.hp)
       if targetID == 2:
           Player.Lupin.hp = Player.Lupin.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Lupin's health is:")
           print(Player.Lupin.hp)
       if targetID == 3:
           Player.Aria.hp = Player.Aria.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Aria's health is:")
           print(Player.Aria.hp)
       if targetID == 4:
           Player.Anges.hp = Player.Anges.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Anges's health is:")
           print(Player.Anges.hp)
       if targetID == 5:
           Player.Sylph.hp = Player.Sylph.hp - Nocturnedamage
           print("Sylph's health is:")
           print(Player.Sylph.hp)

CanNocturneAttack = True
while Player.NocturneEnemy.hp > 0:
   while Player.Sereana.hp > 0 or Player.Lupin.hp > 0 or Player.Aria.hp > 0 or Player.Anges.hp > 0 or Player.Sylph.hp > 0:
       if CanNocturneAttack:
           NocturneAttack()
       CanNocturneAttack = False

while Player.NocturneEnemy.hp > 0:
   NocturneAttack()
   AriaMove()
   AngesMove()
   SylphMove()
   SereanaMove()
   LupinMove()
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code line by line?  If you have any questions about what that means, please just _comment_ down here in response; I'll try to get back to you in a timely manner!

Welcome to SO!

Comment: The indentation that was added has now caused the rest of my code to not run. The battle should not start right away, you should start in a different environment and have to input the direction you want to go. You start in a garden of a house, you can only go north, you go north and are given a prompt for if you want to move forward or not. If you choose yes, the battle starts. This code does not call any of that, it doesn't even call the intro message for the boss battle. This just picks a target for the boss's attack, prints the targets health, and doesn't show anything else, it just ends.

Comment: Unfortunately, understanding what you want to do at a high-level probably won't help me help you.  :)  Please try going to the last place in the code that works, and `print()`ing values of various variables

Comment: Also unfortunately, I should be working on my own little "thing" right now.  But I hope you figure it out!  I might check back later tonight, tomorrow, or later in the week